# Rails how can i include activerecord on vendor script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have script in the folder vendor.
telegram.rb
in this script i need to use active record.
How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643875/how-to-use-activerecord-in-a-ruby-script-outside-rails